# How to get notifications in real time with PostgreSQL (notify/listen), SignalR in ASP.Net core?

Tags: postgresql, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, notify, listen

I am new to the use of postgresql and signalr notifications, I was following this example  https://github.com/Harmen1969/SignalR-Postgresql- but it does not work for me doing it with asp net core, someone could give me some reference on how to do it with net core 2.0 please.
I need to be able to get notification every time there are changes in the database
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

There are some differences between ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR.
See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for details.

Microsoft has mentioned some scaleout differences as well.
It is stated that

> ASP.NET SignalR supports SQL Server and Redis. ASP.NET Core SignalR
>   supports Azure SignalR Service and Redis.